# what does flag -1 in imread of opencv mean

Tags: opencv

I see the code: `Mat imgOrg = imread( fileName, -1 );`. What kind of flag [imreadmodes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da8/group__imgcodecs.html#ga61d9b0126a3e57d9277ac48327799c80) the argument `-1` refers to ?

Comment: The answer is right there at the top of the documentation page you link to in the question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The flags and the correspondings meanings: *from OpenCV* `imgcodecs.hpp`

```
   IMREAD_UNCHANGED            = -1, //!< If set, return the loaded image as is (with alpha channel, otherwise it gets cropped).
   IMREAD_GRAYSCALE            = 0,  //!< If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image (codec internal conversion).
   IMREAD_COLOR                = 1,  //!< If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image.
   IMREAD_ANYDEPTH             = 2,  //!< If set, return 16-bit/32-bit image when the input has the corresponding depth, otherwise convert it to 8-bit.
   IMREAD_ANYCOLOR             = 4,  //!< If set, the image is read in any possible color format.
   IMREAD_LOAD_GDAL            = 8,  //!< If set, use the gdal driver for loading the image.
   IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_2  = 16, //!< If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image and the image size reduced 1/2.
   IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_2      = 17, //!< If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image and the image size reduced 1/2.
   IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_4  = 32, //!< If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image and the image size reduced 1/4.
   IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_4      = 33, //!< If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image and the image size reduced 1/4.
   IMREAD_REDUCED_GRAYSCALE_8  = 64, //!< If set, always convert image to the single channel grayscale image and the image size reduced 1/8.
   IMREAD_REDUCED_COLOR_8      = 65, //!< If set, always convert image to the 3 channel BGR color image and the image size reduced 1/8.
   IMREAD_IGNORE_ORIENTATION   = 128 //!< If set, do not rotate the image according to EXIF's orientation flag.
```

So `-1` means `UNCHANGED`

Answer (score 0):

The mode flags are defined in the `imgcodecs.hpp` https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgcodecs/include/opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp